# Cucumber, Capybara and Rails - pages are not being rendered at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm upgrading a rails 2.3 app to rails 3.2. I'm trying to get our Cucumber coverage back up, and I'm running into a curious issue. Everything is just blank. I've tried running it with webkit and chrome (not selenium, which hasn't been working with my current version of firefox)

```
# config/environments/test.rb
config.cache_classes = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"
config.whiny_nils = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection    = false
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :protocol => "https"}
config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
```

Nothing super strange. And my cucumber env file is all standard, with some separate support files for configuring factory_girl, database_cleaner and capybara. Capybara config:

```
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/webkit'
if ENV["CAPYBARA_JAVASCRIPT_DRIVER"] == "chrome"
  Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
  end
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = (ENV["CAPYBARA_JAVASCRIPT_DRIVER"] || 
  :webkit).to_sym
```

Again, nothing crazy. So I have a simple cucumber feature.

```
Given(/^I am logged in"$/) do
  visit "/login"
end
```

The browser opens, it makes a request to `http://127.0.0.1:45393/login` but nothing happens. No "Not Found" page, no exceptions raised or shown. It just renders a white page. Empty  tags.

If I put a debugger in after the visit line and inspect `page.html`, it returns `""`

I've been tailing the test log. And it shows that Database Cleaner is truncated the DB before the example is run, then ActiveRecord is instantiating the fixtures. It shows:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-11 15:04:53 -0400
```

But it doesn't serve any assets or render anything on the backend either.

I've tried adding to Capybara's other config options such as app_host, run_server, and server_port, but that haven't changed the behavior.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. I'd try debugging on the Rails side.

Comment: Honestly I don't know what the problem ended up being. I threw my branch away when I couldn't figure it out and started the cucumber upgrade over, and this time everything worked. /shrug